# Q: Selenium NoSuchElementException (not explicit wait or iframe)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write code in python that can control an embedded video player (jwplayer) through an automated browser, specifically Smores.tv. (https://smores.tv/watch.php?v=j5UPZpjO&p=Yw4cOKqt) However, when I try to locate the element of the pause/play button or any of the controls it returns a nosuchelement exception.

I've done some research into this, and it seems like the problem could be that the video player is inside an iframe, which i was able to find:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id("jwp-global-frame")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

did not work and the error was still NoSuchElementException. There may be multiple embedded iframes or something similar, but i'm stuck on this issue.(also I am aware of the issue that could come from the page not loading, and since I couldn't find an element for an explicit wait I am currently using an implicit wait for the page to load)

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id("jwp-global-frame")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
pausebutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="player"]/div[9]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]')
pausebutton.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example site, the play button is not inside any Iframe.

So I have tried without switching to iframe and it worked for me.

```
# removed the iframe lines
pausebutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//[@id="player"]/div[9]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]')))
pausebutton.click()
```

You can also find that element with css selector as `.jw-icon-playback`

Comment: I tried running your exact code (except I had to add a ending parenthesis for it to compile) and got a timeout exception. 
'driver.get('https://smores.tv/watch.php?v=j5UPZpjO&p=Yw4cOKqt')
pausebutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//[@id="player"]/div[9]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]')))
pausebutton.click()'

Comment: Did u try with css selector in the answer?

Comment: This works to locate the element, and i had the problem that it couldn't be scrolled into view, but i used actions.move_to_element and moved to the video player ('.jwplayer') then tried to click on the button. this code runs without any errors, but it still doesn't click on the button for some reason.